# DNN v7.2.1 New Install jQuery version Issue

Tags: .net, jquery-ui, dotnetnuke

I have had so many problems getting DNN to remain stable.  This is perhaps my tenth install and problems right off the bat again - v7.2.1 - Clean install, nothing has been altered.  Starting having issues right away with the version of jQuery being run (jQuery 2), I am on XP locally, web server is windows server 2008 R2.  When pages load it throws errors like:

JSON is undefined

OR

Invalid argument dnn.js Code: 0

None of the dropdown boxes or checkboxes are rendering correctly - the pages are also displaying the tooltips as shadowed boxes that only go away when move mouse over them.

I have gone to the Host -> host settings because I wished to  change the version of jQuery being used and set it to  "Use Hosted jQuery Version" but because of these errors, I cannot see the checkbox to select it.  I really need help with this - hopefully someone out there can explain this to me.

Thanks,
S

Comment: You mentioned you're on XP. What browser are you using? jQuery 2 is not supported on old IE versions. It also sounds like it doesn't have a JSON polyfill. Anyways, try a newer browser like FireFox or Chrome and see how it does.

Answer (score 1):

So, DNN ships with jQuery 1.9.1, are you swapping out to a newer version of JQuery?

I only ever recommend using the version of jQuery that ships with your DNN install, newer versions haven't been tested, and likely won't work.